Non-Trivial Solutions to Diophantine Equation $x^3 + x = y^3$
I am searching for non-trivial solutions to Diophantine equations like
$$
x^3 + x = y^3
$$

Put any mathematical expression inside $.$.

Include in a question what you have tried to solve a problem

This question is not well posed. You should state the problem more clearly (for example, are you interested in positive integers, integers, rationals or something else?), you should tell what you have tried before asking here and possibily you should tex your formulas. You can find more informations here: https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Note that for $x>0$ you have
$$x^3<x^3+x<(x+1)^3,$$
and for $x<0$ you have
$$(x-1)^3<x^3+x<x^3.$$
This means $x^3+x$ is not a perfect cube if $x\neq0$, so the unique integral solution is $(x,y)=(0,0)$.

As for rational solutions; let $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ be nonzero integers with $\gcd(X,Y,Z)=1$ such that $x=\frac XZ$ and $y=\frac YZ$. Then
$$Y^3=X^3+XZ^2=X(X^2+Z^2),\tag{1}$$
Let $U:=\gcd(Y,Z)$ and $V:=\gcd(X,Z)$ and $W:=\gcd(X,Y)$. Then from $\gcd(X,Y,Z)=1$ it follows that
$$\gcd(U,V)=\gcd(U,W)=\gcd(V,W)=\gcd(U,X)=\gcd(V,Y)=\gcd(W,Z)=1.$$
Then there are integers $X'$, $Y'$ and $Z'$ such that
$$X=VWX',\qquad Y=UWY',\qquad Z=UVZ',$$
and also $X'$, $Y'$ and $Z'$ are pairwise coprime by definition of $U$, $V$ and $W$. Then from $(1)$ we get
$$Y^3=X(X^2+Z^2)=(VWX')((VWX')^2+(UVZ')^2)=V^3(WX')(W^2X'^2+U^2Z'^2).$$
In particular we see that $V$ divides $Y$. We already saw that $\gcd(V,Y)=1$ and hence $V=1$. Then
$$X'(W^2X'^2+U^2Z'^2)=\frac{Y^3}{W}=U^3W^2Y'^3.\tag{2}$$
Becaues $U$ is coprime to $X'$ we see that $U$ divides the other factor
$$W^2X'^2+U^2Z'^2.\tag{3}$$
Because $U$ divides $U^2Z'^2$ and $U$ is coprime to $W$ and $X'$, it follows that $U$ is coprime to $(3)$ and hence also $U=1$. Then $(2)$ simplifies to
$$X'(W^2X'^2+Z'^2)=W^2Y'^3.\tag{4}$$
Next note that, because $W$ is coprime to $Z'$ and of course $W$ divides $W^2X'^2$, it follows that $W$ is coprime to the factor $W^2X'^2+Z'^2$ above, and so $W^2$ divides $X'$. Conversely, because $X'$ is coprime to $Y'$ we see that $X'$ divides $W^2$, and so we conclude that $X'=\pm W^2$. Then
$$W^2Y'^3=\pm W^2(W^4+Z'^2),\qquad\text{ and so }\qquad Y'^3=\pm(W^4+Z'^2).$$
Replacing $Y'$ by $-Y'$ if necessary, we find that
$$Z'^2+W^4=Y'^3.$$
This is a generalized Fermat equation, which is well-studied. A complete parametrization of the integral solutions, by four separate triples of polynomials, can be found in Appendix A on page 28 of

F.Beukers, The diophantine equation Axp + Byq = Czr
, Duke Math.J. 91(1998), 61-88

